# regex between number(s) and string of text

Tags: regex, parsing

Assume that i have a string of text like `12234 dragon ave`. I want to write a regex that only find the value between 122334 and ave = dragon

I already tried->

`(?<=\d)(.*)(?=ave)`. This will only take out the first digit, so the outcome becomes `2234 dragon`

Thanks for help

Comment: which language is this

Comment: this->VBA or Alteryx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix.

```
(?<=\d\b)(.*)(?=ave)
```

`\d\b` says a digit after which a `word boundary` is present.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jX1rN4/1